# Python argparse combining a flag and a variable

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to be able to specify an option to my program which acts as both a flag and as variable.  For example:
I have an argument called "--logging".  If this argument is not specified, I'd like it to be set to false (i.e. action='store_true'), but if the argument is specified, I'd like to do two things.  1) I'd like to set a default path of "./log_file.log" and 2) I'd like to allow the user to specify a different log file location.

Answer (score 8):

Right, so I've come up with my own solution for this one.  It relies on nargs.  Here is the code first:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# example.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example of a single flag acting as a boolean and an option.")
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const="bar", default=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.foo:
  print args.foo
else:
  print "Using the default, boolean False."
```

Given that example, here is what happens when we use it in the three possible situations:

```
> ./example.py
  Using the default, boolean False.
> ./example.py --foo
  bar
> ./example.py --foo baz
  baz
```

Hopefully the above is pretty self-explanatory.  In case it isn't, what is going on is that nargs='?' will use the 'default' value if the flag is not specified (boolean False in our case), the const value if the flag is specified without arguments, and the argument if the flag is specified with an argument.  Be careful to not put any quotes around False; False is a built in type (boolean) and 'False' or "False" will evaluate as true.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is no issue. You can use this form explained in the excellent [PyMOTW about argparse](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/argparse/)

```
import argparse    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()


parser.add_argument('--logging', action='store_true', default=False,
                    dest='logging_on',
                    help='Activate the logging')

results = parser.parse_args()
```

You can use the logging_on to test and output values later on in your code (replace it by what makes sense for you). You can also use either a config file or/and an argument for the file log path.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem.  I wanted to not only make it a True/False flag, but also allow it to hold a default value or a custom value.  I've solved my own problem below!